# How do I get a list of folders and sub folders without the files?

Tags: cmd, directory, subdirectory

I am trying to print a list of the ***folders*** and ***sub folders*** of a directory to a file.

When I run **`dir /s/b/o:n > f.txt`**, I get a list of the files also. I only need the folders and  sub folders.

Anyone know is this possible to do this from command line interface?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Try this:

```
dir /s /b /o:n /ad > f.txt
```

Comment: Hi, this above command also lists the hidden and system folders. Can we ignore this (even if Windows Folders option has been to display such folders)

Comment: thanks from me too! Do you stil think this will be supported in Windows 10 - I mean DOS commands?

Comment: Not sure why you mix notation?, just use either `dir /s /b /o:n /a:d > f.txt` or `dir /s /b /on /ad > f.txt`. Personally I use the `:` approach for attributes of a switch as it's clearer what is going on.

Comment: @Lankymart Very good point! Never haven given much attention about the different ways of the parameter notation.

Answer (score 20):

```
 Displays a list of files and subdirectories in a directory.

 DIR [ drive:][path][filename] [/A[[:]attributes]] [/B] [/C] [/D] [/L] [/N]
  [/O[[:]sortorder]] [/P] [/Q] [/R] [/S] [/T[[:]timefield]] [/W] [/X] [/4]

  [drive:][path][filename]
          Specifies drive, directory, and/or files to list.

  /A          Displays files with specified attributes.
  attributes   D  Directories                R  Read-only files
           H  Hidden files               A  Files ready for archiving
           S  System files               I  Not content indexed files
           L  Reparse Points             -  Prefix meaning not
```

just set type of desired file attribute, in your case /A:D (directory)

dir /s/b/o:n/A:D > f.txt

Answer (score 7):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on any answer. In one of the comments, someone has asked how to ignore the hidden folders in the list. Below is how you can do this.

```
dir /b /AD-H
```

Comment: And add /s to recurse subfolders

Answer (score 6):

I am using this from PowerShell:

```
dir -directory -name -recurse > list_my_folders.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

I used `dir /s /b /o:n /a:d`, and it worked perfectly, just make sure you let the file finish writing, or you'll have an incomplete list.

Answer (score 3):

`dir /ad /b /s` will give the required answer.