# How can I get a count of all sub-folders with a specific name in Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd, command-prompt, command-line-interface

I am trying to figure out how many sub-folders contain a folder called "img", so I want to implement a recursive count of all subfolders called "img", if this is possible.

Also, how can I do a count that is one level deep? i.e it will look only one folder deep for all folders called "img"?

So, if my folder structure was :

```
>folder1
  >img
>folder2
  >subfolder
    >img
>folder3
   >subfolder
      >subsubfolder
        >img
>folder4
  >img
```

The first part would return 4, and the second script would return 2.

Is this possible to do either from CMD or with some Windows tool?

I've had a look around and the closest I could find was a CLI script to print all folders and sub-folders to a file :

```
dir /directory:n /ad > f.txt
```

[from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078421/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-folders-and-subfolders-without-the-files).

Which I could then copy paste into Notepad++ and do some manual messing around with...but I was hoping there was a cleaner/faster solution than this in case I ever come across this in the future. What would I need to write for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
SET /a onelevelcount=0
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /ad "%sourcedir%" 2^>nul'
 ) DO (
 IF EXIST "%sourcedir%\%%a\img\." SET /a onelevelcount+=1
)
ECHO one level down=%onelevelcount%
SET /a grandtotal=0
FOR /f %%c IN ('dir /s /ad "%sourcedir%"  2^>nul^|findstr /i /e /r "\\img"') DO SET /a grandtotal+=1
ECHO grand total=%grandtotal%

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

As for **how** you'd figure it out - practice makes perfect. Lots of examples on SO.

Answer (score -2):

type the folowing code on notepad and save it as .dll

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
SET /a onelevelcount=0
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /ad "%sourcedir%" 2^>nul'
 ) DO (
 IF EXIST "%sourcedir%\%%a\img\." SET /a onelevelcount+=1
)
ECHO one level down=%onelevelcount%
SET /a grandtotal=0
FOR /f %%c IN ('dir /s /ad "%sourcedir%"  2^>nul^|findstr /i /e /r "\\img"') DO SET /a grandtotal+=1
ECHO grand total=%grandtotal%

GOTO :EOF`enter code here`
```